# Node monitors scripts doesn't work after edit files

Tags: 20.04, nodejs, web-development

I develop in Node.js and today I instaled nodemon to run a project that I doing. But It's doesn't works, I searched in many foruns about that but I'm not found solutions. So I tried another options like forever and pm2 and both had same issue. Can someone help me fix this? I didn't have this problem in last version of ubuntu.

Comment: What instructions are you following? What exactly does not work?

Comment: I execute nodemon server.js, after I edit and save some file js on src folder, nodemon don't catch alteration and restart.